# Dict object not callable com requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make an API call using python requests. The flow is:

A POST request to get the token, then an GET request, passing the previous TOKEN and a midway token (this API calls another one that I can't call directly).

Here is my code:

```
def get_ipi (token):
    url = api_url
    auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)}
    headers = {'secAuthorization': 'Bearer CHILD_API_TOKEN'}

    resp = requests.get(url, headers = headers, auth = auth)

    print(resp.status_code)
```

For some reason I'm getting a type error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I followed the request doc page example, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Please give a [mre] with the full traceback.

Comment: This is the most I can post, the URLs is protected and in company. I'm currently looking for some other API I can get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `Authorization` as a `header` not `auth`, so basically merge both the `auth` and `header` dicts and pass it as a single dict as `header`

```
headers = { 'secAuthorization': 'Bearer CHILD_API_TOKEN', 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
          }
```

and then make the call

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

Comment: It seems you were right,the SSL error is the one I need to solve not the dict. The error existed because the auth parameter don't accept dicts. Already tried the verify = False.